# Gradle does not resolve my dependencies anymore - the repositories are set however

Tags: java, gradle

For no apparent reason Gradle seems not fail resolving my dependencies. I added the `jcenter` and `google` repository because I thought things moved over to there but still the resolution fails.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:19.1.0')

    compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
    implementation 'javax-servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    implementation 'javax-servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23'
    implementation 'google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.zaxxar:HirakiCP:4.0.3'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}
```

Error log:

```
Execution failed for task ':user-init:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':user-init:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find javax-servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax-servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax-servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax-servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :user-init
   > Could not find javax-servlet:jstl:1.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax-servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax-servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/javax-servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.pom
     Required by:
         project :user-init
   > Could not find google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/google/cloud/sql/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8/1.2.1/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.2.1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/google/cloud/sql/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8/1.2.1/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.2.1.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/google/cloud/sql/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8/1.2.1/mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8-1.2.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :user-init
   > Could not find com.zaxxar:HirakiCP:4.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/zaxxar/HirakiCP/4.0.3/HirakiCP-4.0.3.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/zaxxar/HirakiCP/4.0.3/HirakiCP-4.0.3.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/zaxxar/HirakiCP/4.0.3/HirakiCP-4.0.3.pom
     Required by:
         project :user-init

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

I have no explaination to that and am somewhat confused. Maybe less drinking on the weekends might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows you the failing dependencies. The group IDs are all wrong and you have a typo on `HikariCP`. Here are the correct declarations:

```
compileOnly 'com.google.cloud.functions:functions-framework-api:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
implementation 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23'
implementation 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.2.1'
implementation 'com.zaxxer:HikariCP:4.0.3'
```